# TypeError using Format in Python

Tags: python, format

I have a numpy.ndarray of the following structure:

```
   array([[ 7963.92759169, -2931.3518914 ,  3360.79428745],
   [ 7964.28495515, -2930.99452794,  3361.15165092],
   [ 7965.60367246, -2929.67581063,  3362.47036823]])
```

I am trying to limit the digits after decimal to 2 with the below code:

```
for (label, score) in zip(lables, scoring_fn):
   print("[INFO] {}: {:.2f}".format(label, float(score)))
```

With this, I get the error "TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.**format**". Could anyone suggest on how to correct this error?

Answer (score 1):

Or use `np.ndarray.round`:

```
arr = arr.round(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print(YourArray)
```

example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 7963.92759169, -2931.3518914 ,  3360.79428745],
   [ 7964.28495515, -2930.99452794,  3361.15165092],
   [ 7965.60367246, -2929.67581063,  3362.47036823]])
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print(a)
```

output:

```
[[ 7963.93 -2931.35  3360.79]
 [ 7964.28 -2930.99  3361.15]
 [ 7965.6  -2929.68  3362.47]]
```

Comment: I tried using printoptions, as you could see in your output, it is no longer an array of integers (comma is not there between the numbers). So I could not access the array using index going further

Comment: using index you can print like this: print(a[0][0].round(2))